# What to do after running geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, console

I'm new to ethereum, I followed the installation guide and chose to go with the Geth Go-implementation.

The first command i run was `geth --console` that downloaded all the blocks, one issue though is that it keeps doing so since blocks are mined quite often. Should I let it continue?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum.SE! It's not clear what you are asking here. Could you add some more details on what you want to do? And in addition, this might be too broad, please try to ask specific questions only and not more than one question per thread.

Comment: Thanks,   Well I would like to start developing Dapps using Solidity. How do I get the IDE?

Comment: @Kizito I suggest you edit the title and question to say that, or delete this and start again.

Comment: Did that answer your question? You can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick.

Comment: @eth please help.. I want to transfer erc20 tokens to the other ether address on a main network , i know that testrpc is for test network but what we need to do for connecting to main network ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `geth attach` to recieve a console of your running geth instance and attach it to it.

After that you can run commands in that terminal. Try `eth`, `net` or `admin`.

Or for example to get the connected peers count:

```
> net.peerCount
12
```

Or check the latest block number:

```
> eth.blockNumber
1155636
```

Check out the [full reference on command line options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

Comment: Did that answer your question? You can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick.