# Running network commands

Tags: go-ethereum, network

I'm an ethereum newbie and have installed ethereum on mac using commands :

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

referenced from https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/installing_mac.html

Reading https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/connecting.html

Where are the commands run from ?  For example the command `> net.listening` is executed from a cli ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those commands are run from inside a running Geth session, which has been started by passing the `console` command. This gives you an interactive Javascript environment and command line.

In its simplest form, from your (Mac) command line:

```
geth console
```

However, on starting a Geth instance you also start the process of downloading the entire blockchain in the background. Have a look at some of the [other flags](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly/4210#4210) you should be passing to optimise the process.

Comment: 'geth console' started instantaneously for me, im not sure if it started a download of entire blockchain, where can I check this ?

Comment: If the blockchain is being downloaded then the `~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata` directory will be increasing in size (it'll be populated with files). You should also be seeing console logs to indicate as such, but that may depend on what the default logging level is on Mac.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/what-to-do-after-running-geth?rq=1